# Using SharePoint Designer to design a SharePoint 365 (online) site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm new to SharePoint development and design. Someone recommended using SharePoint Designer as a quicker way to have the site have a specific look that is different from the SharePoint Look Book. We want sections of our page to have borders with rounded edges, and specific color headers. I found several contradicting articles about using SharePoint Designer. Do you recommend using it on the latest version of SharePoint online in 2022? Have you had any success, or have you encountered any issues?

I enable scripting on my site. I tried connecting SharePoint Designer 2013 to my SharePoint online site successfully, but would like to know if it's a good idea to move forward with it.

Comment: Hi, you should ask this on the SharePoint Stack Exchange site, not Stack Overflow, since this isn't particularly a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019#sharepoint-designer) SP Designer is supported on the latest On-Premises version of SharePoint(2019) on the bare minimum. But as you can see it is a product that is steadily heading to it's end-of-support/deprecation lifecycle.

Also, as you can understand, since it's development was halted since the 2013 version, a lot have changed since then, and many of the new features are not even supported by SP Designer.

If your are trying to make modifications to a SharePoint Online site, I would suggest using more [modern tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/)(PowerApps, Power Automate, Modern UI, SPFx etc) and leaving SP Designer to it's way to deprecation.

You can also, update your question in terms of what you are trying to achieve and we could propose you some ideas :)